# How to automatically make test data according to sql statement?

Tags: mysql, code-generation

I am not sure whether or not there exists a tool that can generate test data according to sql statement.
And, if so, does anyone ever use it?

Comment: Try googling test data generator.

Comment: Spawner Data Generator but i think you have to configure it